# Analyzing user driving pattern data

Tags: data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

so I have a lot of GPXs of users driving data from a game project where object which are placed on the road and then the user collects it. I want to somehow analyze these data to find out how users tend to drive given different objects, which ones draw them the most, which ones draw least. I have not done any data analysis before, so how can I analyze these data to get this sort of information? This might sound very novice, but yeah any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably like to do this in Python if you are novice, and then you can use a library like this one ([gpxpy](https://pypi.org/project/gpxpy/)) to explore your data.
That is a GPX parser, I believe it will provide you with the data you like to see.

In their documentation you can see that you can use it like that :

```py
import gpxpy
import gpxpy.gpx

# Open a file
gpx_file = open('yourfile.gpx', 'r')

# Parse the file
gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)

# Iterate over the tracks
for track in gpx.tracks:
    for segment in track.segments:
        for pt in segment.points:
            print(f'Point at ({pt.latitude},{pt.longitude}) -> {pt.elevation}')

for waypoint in gpx.waypoints:
    print(f'waypoint {waypoint.name} -> ({waypoint.latitude},{waypoint.longitude})')

for route in gpx.routes:
    print('Route:')
    for pt in route.points:
        print(f'Point at ({pt.latitude},{pt.longitude}) -> {pt.elevation}')
```

Once you have those points you can calculate the distances, speeds, etc. from the coordinates.

Comment: I have used that library. Do you have any more idea?

Comment: Well, then can you explain what you did already ?? Put some code snippets, etc. and tell us what you really want to do.